# Trying to find instance of regex pattern ['"]rm[ ].*['"] using grep

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I'm trying to find lines similar to these input strings. Basically 
-a single or double quote
-followed by 1 or more blanks
-followed by rm
-followed by 1 or more spaces

Below would be some example matches.

```
build2('rm myfile')
build2(" rm myfile')
'rm myfile'
```

I can use a regex tester like regexpal dot com and it works fine but how would I do it using grep if my input file is called myfile.txt? I've tried the command from shell prompt below but grep does nothing but response with a > character on the next line.

```
grep "['"] *rm *" myfile.txt
```

Comment: What OS are you using? I would first check grep for what delimiter it needs, then the OS to construct the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use double quotes around your call to grep. Therefore, you need to escape the double quote inside your pattern.

```
grep "['\"] *rm *" myfile.txt
```